# -notmatch '.JPG|.PNG' then to scan results with sigcheck

Tags: powershell, security, sysinternals

check users in $directory recursive and if no files contain extension JPG,PNG etc then run the results with sigcheck excluding those files?

```
$directory = dir E:\Users 
$SigcheckPath = "C:\Windows\temp\sigcheck.exe"
$path1 = "download"
$path2 = "documents"

foreach ($dir in $directory) {
    $filepath = Get-ChildItem E:\Users\$dir\downloads -recurse | where {! $_.PSIsContainer}
    foreach ($file in $filepath) {
        if ($file -notmatch '.jpg|.png|.gif') { 
            & $SigcheckPath -nobanner -a -h -s -v -vt -c F:\Users\$dirz\downloads > C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir.csv 
        }
    }
}
```

It should give output to a single file with .csv all the results for user for that specific directory!

Comment: Change `>` to `>>`?

Comment: It didn't work with ```>>```

Comment: `>>` appends rather than overwrites

Comment: It's not going through the loop replacing directory in F:\users\$dir\downloads ? It shud actually check Users directory and iterate with all the users. example F:\users\aaa\downloads F:\users\bbb\downloads . I am not sure how to get it to iterate the $dir values; rest of the script works fine and thanks for ```>>```

Comment: You need to change `foreach ($dir in $directory)` to `foreach ($dir in $directory.Name)`

Comment: I got it to work with this ```foreach ($dir in $directory) { 
 $filepath = Get-ChildItem E:\Users\$dir\Downloads -Recurse -Attributes !Directory
 foreach ($file in $filepath){
$file | Where-Object { $_.Fullname -notmatch '.gif|.jpg|.png|.txt' } |  Select -Expand FullName
 }
 }```